# $index inside ng-click not print a number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I create ng-click inside ng-repeat and I want to change a variable currentpage with $index value. But it is not work properly, $index print as a string not return a number. This is my code:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(pagenumber) track by $index">
    <a href="#" ng-click="currentpage=$index">{{$index+1}}</a>
</li>
```

Update: I want to write ng-click statement inline in html, not call a function in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function `setCurrentPage` :

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(pagenumber) track by $index">
    <a href="#" ng-click="setCurrentPage($index)">{{$index+1}}</a>
</li>
```

***In the controller :***

```
$scope.setCurrentPage = function (index) {
    $scope.currentpage = index;
}
```

Note: `index` is already a Number, no need for conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I want to write an argument inline in html. Is angularJS support this?

Comment: Yes, angular supports this, you could write `<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count = 0">Increment</button>`. But be aware that in `ngRepeat`, each item gets its own scope, therefore by going *inline* you might be setting not the instance you want to set.